# how to overload operator++ in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

Help me, please, realize overload operator++ in doubly linked list.
I have a two classes A and B.

```
class A {
private:
    int h;
    int a;
public:
    A *next, *prev;

friend A operator ++(A &, int);
};

A operator ++(A &t, int) {
    A temp = t;
    temp.h++;
    temp.a++;
    return temp;
}


class B {
private:
    A *head, *tail;
public:
    void incValue();
};

void B::incValue() {
    while(head != nullptr) {
        head++;
        head = head -> next;
    }
}
```

After execution method incValue() head = NULL
I don't understand why this don't work.

P.S. This code must be eq. head++

```
head -> setH(head -> getH() + 1);
head -> setA(head -> getA() + 1);
```

Comment: `while(head != nullptr)` this causes it to loop until you have `head` == to `nullptr` which (wild guess) is `NULL`. When you get this as true you break the loop. Hence when you come out head is NULL

Comment: Is `head` an array?  If not, what is `head++` doing, do you think?

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: head is first node in list. I want head++ to do head -> h = head -> h + 1

Comment: From a design point of view, it isn't great to have an increment-like operator or member function that changes the state of a linked list. Better to implement iterators for this.

Comment: Do not change the value of head or tail to traverse the list. Use a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overload operator ++ you need to support some data member of the linked list that will define the current position in the list. Also you need a member function that will reset the current position in the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the overloaded `operator++` for `A` you need to call `(*head)++` in your `B::incValue` method.

Answer (score 0):

First. You overloading operator to use first parameter as a class -> you don't need to make operator friend.

```
class A {
private:
    int h;
    int a;
public:
    A *next;
    A *prev;
    void operator ++ ( int ); 
};
```

This overloaded operator will work with object of class A. So to use it just write:

```
A a;
a++;
```

And realization of this operator will be:

```
void A::operator ++ ( int )
{
  h++;
  a++;
}
```

You realization will work only like:

```
A a;
a = a++;
```

Because operator ++ return new copy of A object, but incremented h and a members.

Second. About walking in list:
Your **while** will stop when head == NULL, so after execution while loop head pointer will be equal to 0. So, that loop statement `head++` will be executed for every object.